# ViewController with different behavior on hidden Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I have a ViewController which has a hidden navigationBar (supported by a NavigationController). The problem is that the navigation bar is rendering a black image on the bottom of the nav bar.

[image: First View with Navigation Controller, but with hidden nav bar]

[image: Second View, but without the correct renderization on the nav bar.]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a scroll view to render the rest of your views?

Comment: I would go through all your related views and make sure none of them have a black background that shouldn't. Something could be peeking through the hierarchy of views you don't suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS 11. If you try on a lower target you´ll see that it will work. The problem is that the navigation bar goes up like 10 pixels on iOS 11. Not much to do at the moment for this.

Comment: Yep, that's what i was thinking. The only thing left is to wait for new release. Thank you!